# Nginx + uWSGI basic configuration

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm new to both, I got to run 2 Django skeleton apps (just shows the "It works!" page) using Emperor, but I want to try it *without* Emperor. (to better understand how it works)

My nginx.conf:

```
# snipped...
server { 
  listen 92; 
  server_name example.com; 
  access_log /home/john/www/example.com/logs/access.log; 
  error_log /home/john/www/example.com/logs/error.log; 

  location / { 
    include uwsgi_params; 
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8001; 
  } 
}
# snipped...
```

And I start uWSGI by:

```
$ uwsgi --ini /home/john/www/example.com/uwsgi.ini
```

With uwsgi.ini being:

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8001
chdir = /home/john/www/example.com/example
module = example.wsgi
master = True
home = /home/john/Envs/example.com
```

Once uwsgi and nginx are running, I can access `localhost:8001`, but not `localhost:92`.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the uwsgi process to serve applications using the http protocol.  This feature is meant mainly for developer convenience.  You should instead tell it to use the uwsgi protocol:

```
[uwsgi]
protocol = uwsgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
chdir = /home/john/www/example.com/example
module = example.wsgi
master = True
home = /home/john/Envs/example.com
```